# Vim: Is it possible to do let g:netrw_keepdir=0 for NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is it possible to do `let g:netrw_keepdir=0` for NERDTree?

When I change a directory, there I want to create a new file.

So how can I set this as current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to make the directory you just entered via NERDTree the `cwd`?

If so, you could look at NERDTree's documentation (`:help nerdtree`) and see what it says about `NERDTreeChDirMode`.

If you want to make this behaviour the default (no matter how you open/create files), adding the following line to your .vimrc will change the working directory to the one containing the active buffer.

```
set autochdir
```